# How to solve a long system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

We know that there are lots of ways to solve a system of equations, however I can't seem to find a way to solve a long system of equation just by hand without using a computer. the system I'm focused on is this: $$\begin{cases}
x_0+0^1x_1+0^2x_2+0^3x_3+...+0^nx_n=c_0 \\
x_0+1^1x_1+1^2x_2+1^3x_3+...+1^nx_n=c_1 \\
x_0+2^1x_1+2^2x_2+2^3x_3+...+2^nx_n=c_2 \\
.\\
.\\
.\\
x_0+n^1x_1+n^2x_2+n^3x_3+...+n^nx_n=c_n \\
\end{cases}$$
we can see that there is a pattern in the coefficients, but I wonder if there is a general form that I can use to find each variable in function of the other coefficients
$$x_0=f_0(c_0, c_1,...,c_n)\\x_1=f_1(c_0, c_1,...,c_n)\\..\\x_n=f_n(c_0, c_1,...,c_n)$$ so far I tried the reduced row echelon form (RREF) method, but the time needed to solve this kind of system depends on "n". my desired outcome is to find (if there is) a general form to solve this kind of systems.

Comment: My guess is that there is no easy way out here. However, in theory this sort of system of equations can be written as an matrix equation then solved with something involving diagonalization. Perhaps try that, or someone better at linear algebra can help.

Comment: @person Indeed matrix would help in this case, however a big matrix with nxn dimentions is hard to deal with. that's why I asked the question to see if there is a better way, my guess is there could be a solution involving some kind of a sum, but I can seem to find it.

Comment: http://www.vesnik.math.rs/vol/mv19303.pdf

Comment: If you reformulate to $$\mathbf{M}\cdot\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{c}$$ you get a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) like matrix, but your indices don't run to $n-1$ and instead a square matrix. If you are able to reduce then you have some traction

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful